# Segmentation fault on HOG opencv ocl module

Tags: c++, opencv, opencl

i'm having a problem with opencv implementation of the HOG algorithm in the module ocl.
The problem is not on the output of the detector but actually on the return of the main method. That is i can compile and run the application and get the results but when the application exists it crashes with a segmentation fault.
I'm using the opencv version 2.4.8 compiled with mingw, but this problem persists on other opencv versions.

Here is a minimalist example of the code that gives me the reported problem:

```
int main()
{
    cv::ocl::DevicesInfo devices;
    cv::ocl::getOpenCLDevices(devices);
    cv::ocl::setDevice(devices[0]);

    cv::ocl::HOGDescriptor desc;
    desc.setSVMDetector(cv::ocl::HOGDescriptor::getDefaultPeopleDetector());

    cv::Mat t_img = cv::imread("view.png");

    std::vector<cv::Rect> hoghypothesis;

    cv::ocl::oclMat cleanImgGpu;
    cv::cvtColor(t_img, t_img, CV_BGR2BGRA);
    cleanImgGpu.upload(t_img);
    desc.detectMultiScale(cleanImgGpu, hoghypothesis, 0.09, cv::Size(8,8), cv::Size(0,0), 1.2, 0.0);

    for(unsigned int pl = 0; pl < hoghypothesis.size(); pl++)
        cv::rectangle(t_img, hoghypothesis.at(pl), cv::Scalar(255,255,255),2);


    cv::resize(t_img, t_img, cv::Size(1366,768));

    cv::namedWindow("origFrame",1);
    cv::imshow("origFrame", t_img);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    cv::destroyAllWindows();

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks, Américo.

Additional info:
When i run the program normally it gives me a appcrash with this info:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: OpenCLTests.exe
  Application Version:  0.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    00000000
  Fault Module Name:    ntdll.dll
  Fault Module Version: 6.1.7601.18229
  Fault Module Timestamp:   51fb164a
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 0000000000019a8a
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    2070
  Additional Information 1: 9646
  Additional Information 2: 9646f69d7d90104bc2f332551ea877c7
  Additional Information 3: 0f02
  Additional Information 4: 0f02418e0eb39adff911c83cce610af7
```

On debug mode it just gives me a SIGSEGV signal. Its not even an exception so i can't try/catch it.

Comment: Please compile your program with debug flags enabled. Then run it. When it crashes, please cut the stacktrace and paste it into your question. That would help people identifying your problem.